# Solr MM (Min Match) and q.alt behaviour

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to implement a search that iterates over new signups at our site and looks for duplicates.

For prototyping and playing around I have indexed my test users with the fields

- firstName
- lastName
- city

So say we have a new user whose name is Rob Lewis and he lives in Seattle. I want to do an MM search for all existing users that match at least 2 of firstName:Rob lastName:Lewis city:Seattle.

So I want to find

- All Rob Lewises
- All Robs that live in Seattle
- All Lewises that live in Seattle

I thought I should be able to do this with dismax (or edismax) with

- q.alt=firstName:Rob lastName:Lewis city:Seattle
- mm=2

But it does not seem to work. The MM has no effect on the results and I just get the same list as if I did not specify MM (i.e. all Robs, all Lewises and all users that live in Seattle).

Additionally just for testing I tried mm=100%, which I would expect to match only Rob Lewis in Seattle. However it again matched all Robs, all Lewises and all users that live in Seattle).

How can I accomplish my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, there is no need to be using `q.alt` - you can use `q` directly with `defType=edismax`. I'll answer the rest of the question as it is stated (using `q.alt`).

The `q.alt` parameter uses the Lucene Query Syntax by default, and `mm` is only recognized as an (e)dismax argument.

You can instruct Solr to use the (e)dismax parser for the q.alt option as well through localParams:

```
q.alt={!dismax}firstName:Rob lastName:Lewis city:Seattle
```

You can also provide a specific mm value through localparams:

```
q.alt={!dismax mm=2}firstName:Rob lastName:Lewis city:Seattle
```

Comment: You are right ! I had tried using q with dismax and it did not work when specifying the fields (it worked without the fields i.e. "Rob Lewis Seattle", but that was not the desired behaviour). However with edismax it does seem to handle the query with fields as I expected.